# Bot framework V4 Nodejs chat history logging

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have to log the user-bot conversation in CosmosDB for audit/history purpose. In V3 using .Net, I was using table logger module, like the below code.

*builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(account, chatHistoryTableName));*

Now we are upgrading/rewriting the bot to V4 in NodeJS. Please guide if there is a similar approach available for V4 in NodeJS to save the entire conversation?

Answer (score 3):

This example hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1266

It uses AzureBlobTranscriptStore  and TranscriptLoggerMiddleware

```
const { AzureBlobTranscriptStore  } = require('botbuilder-azure');
const { TranscriptLoggerMiddleware } = require('botbuilder-core');

// Get blob service configuration as defined in .bot file
const blobStorageConfig = botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(BLOB_CONFIGURATION);
// The transcript store has methods for saving and retrieving bot conversation transcripts.
let transcriptStore = new AzureBlobTranscriptStore({storageAccountOrConnectionString: blobStorageConfig.connectionString,
                                                    containerName: blobStorageConfig.container
                                                    });
// Create the middleware layer responsible for logging incoming and outgoing activities
// into the transcript store.
var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(transcriptStore);
adapter.use(transcriptMiddleware);
```

Comment: It is working and able to see the activity JSON in blob storage. But I noticed that the user entered messages are not getting saved. Is there anything else to capture user typed messages?

Comment: I just tried the sample again, and user typed messages are saved into the transcript store.  How are you determining they are not?

Comment: I am looking at the Blob Block contents in Azure Blob storage > webchat > conversationid. I can see the JSON activities listed. Is there any other way to verify?

Comment: hmmm... I'm not sure then.  When I run the sample, all activities are being stored in the transcript store.  Are you using the sample as/is? or have you made changes to it?

Comment: I haven't tried with the sample one, I am using own bot in V4. How are you verifying the messages - same way as I mentioned (Azure Blob storage > webchat > conversationid)?

Comment: If you can share your implementation somewhere, i'll look it over and try to help. This example:https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1266 does save the user messages and bot replies into the store.

Comment: I was trying with the sample code, but I am getting following exception. 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at Promise (D:\my-chat-bot\node_modules\botbuilder-azure\lib\azureBlobTranscriptStore.js:248:24)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.args (D:\my-chat-bot\node_modules\botbuilder-azure\lib\azureBlobTranscriptStore.js:246:24)

Comment: :( apparently a bug was introduced with BotBuilder 4.3.2 ... if you change the package.json to stick with 4.2.1 it will work ("botbuilder": "~4.2.1",
        "botbuilder-azure": "~4.2.1",
        "botframework-config": "~4.2.1",)

Comment: Not sure, I am getting a different error now. BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR - TypeError: client.addUserAgentInfo is not a function

Comment: There is a PR to fix this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/809  It just has not yet been merged and released.

Comment: @EricDahlvang - This is super useful,  thank you. I've implemented your example and it's logging my transcript to my blob storage but it keeps throwing a couple of errors:   `[onTurnError]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined` and 
`BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR - Error: BotFrameworkAdapter.sendActivity(): missing conversation id.`  Any ideas? I've posted a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235252/debugging-transcript-logging-middleware-in-node-js-bot-framework-v4-4)

Answer (score 1):

This should provide a good start.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: I have tried this, to save the conversation data. But the need here is to save entire conversation activity so that the complete chat can be recreated. .Net has option as explained in https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/22.conversation-history. Looking for similar option in NodeJS.