# Saving conversation transcripts - bot framework v4.4 node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

Does anyone know how to save transcripts using the latest version (4.4) of the bot framework in Node JS?  Or is there some documentation available?

I've read through the official docs and there is an example in C#, but nothing for Node JS.  I'm not familiar with C# and all the other threads I can find are for older versions of the framework.

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO Rob! Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011499/5209435).

Comment: Thanks @Matt! It's pretty similar to the question you linked to. Only difference for v4.4 is that the keys are kept in the .env file rather than the .botConfig.

Comment: Awesome, so you're all sorted now?

Comment: Pretty much. The transcripts are saved, but are all in individual files.  Do you know of a way to save them that is easier to review?

Comment: Here is the default implementation for the [transcriptLogger class](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/transcriptLogger.ts). It looks like you can extend the TranscriptScore class like they do [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder/src/fileTranscriptStore.ts) you could then make your own that logs into a database and you could retrieve by conversationId and time stamp ascending it something like that.

Comment: Thanks again Matt!  Really appreciate your help.