# How can I save and retrieve conversation data from the bot using Microsoft Bot Framework version 4?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using Bot Framework SDK 4 Nodejs, and am going to deploy the bot on Skype. I need to save the conversation data/ chat history of the bot for every user.

I tried using the conversationState property accessor but it returns some JSON having data about the general chat/turn context - like the buttons the bot has prompted etc. 
I want the sequential chat history like :- 
Bot: "What do you want to do?". 
User : "I want to generate a ticket" and so on...

For example when you run the Bot locally on the Bot Framework Emulator, it displays some logs at the bottom right hand corner. I want those exact logs or something similar to be stored and used in my bot.

Please help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up that Skype support is going to be dropped in the [very near future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). 

_Skype for Business channel in Bot Framework is being deprecated on June 30, 2019.

No new bots will be able to add Skype for Business channel after that date. Existing bots will continue to work until October 31, 2019._

Comment: Take a look at this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot framework V4 Nodejs chat history logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999417/bot-framework-v4-nodejs-chat-history-logging)