# Reviewing saved chats in Azure blob storage in bot based on botframework v4 node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am saving transcripts from my bot that is based on the core-bot sample and written in node.js

I used this solution to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011499/12456146

I'm trying to figure out how I can extract the chats from the blob and present or review the saved chat in a nice format, but I have been unable to so far.

I haven't found any references at all for this, so please help me out if you can.

Comment: Hi , has your issue been solved ?

Comment: Hi, this was really helpful, but would you happen to know how to do the same thing using the azure nodejs storage SDK ?

Comment: Hi , I have updated my answer , appended sample code to get chat logs using nodejs storage sdk. Pls mark my post as an answer if it is helpful for you .

Comment: Thanks a ton, Sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `AzureBlobTranscriptStore` and `TranscriptLoggerMiddleware` to log your bot chatting history, logs will be stored in your blob storage under folder: `<channel name>/<conversation ID|channel>`. And each activity will be logged as a .json file.

For instance, I use bot emulator to test it, all logs are stored as below : 
[image]

You can use [Azure nodejs storage SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) or [Azure Az Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.3.0) to read them.

In this case I use Azure powershell to get chat logs , try the powershell below :

```
$storageAccount = "<your storage account name>"
$resourceGroup = "<your resource group name>"
$containerName = "<your container name>"
$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -name $storageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
$channel="emulator"
$conversationID = "<conversationID>"
$prefix = $channel+"/"+$conversationID 

$chatlogs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Prefix $prefix -Container $containerName -Context $storage.Context 

$tempPath = "d:/temp/"
mkdir $tempPath
foreach($log in $chatlogs){
    $jsonFile = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $log.Name -Container $containerName -Context $storage.Context -Destination $tempPath -Force
    Get-Content -Raw -Path ($tempPath+$jsonFile.Name) | ConvertFrom-Json | select type,timestamp,from,recipient,text
}

Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $tempPath
```

You can find conversation ID in emulator here : 
[image]

Result :

[image]

Hope it helps.

**Update :**

Try the code below to get chatlogs content by storage nodejs SDK :

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');

var storageAccount = "<storage account name>"
var key = "<storage key>"
var container ="chatlog"
var conversationID = "<conversation ID>"
var channel = "emulator"
var prefix = channel + "/" + conversationID

var blobService = azure.createBlobService(storageAccount,key);

 blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(container,prefix,null,function(err, results, resp){

    results.entries.forEach(element => {

     blobService.getBlobToText(container,element.name,function(err, results, resp){console.log(results);
     });

  });
 });
```

Result :

[image]

More samples about nodejs storage SDK [see here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/examples/samples) .