# chat history logs in bot framework v4 node js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have tried all the answers related to saving transcript using node js. I have found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#blob-transcript-storage-implementation for c# implementation . can someone help me with detailed example to store the conversation history in node js bot framework v4 using AzureBlobTranscriptStore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999417/bot-framework-v4-nodejs-chat-history-logging